# What happens when all replicas of a piece of data fail in a data-center?

Tags: storage, distributed, distributed-computing

Distributed storage architectures in modern-day data centers are designed such that there are 2-3 replicas of each piece of data, so that it is still available when a machine fails.

As I understand it, there is still a non-zero probability of all replicas failing, and given the scale of operations, there must be instances where this may happen. How do large data centers protect against this kind of failure, especially when it's important data, like your email, or images? Even further redundancy can only further make such failures unlikely, but not impossible.

Comment: Using replicas, redundancy as well as distributed parity will make the failure-without-means-of-recovery probability very low. For especially important data, additional off-site backups lowers it even more. This discussion is almost along line _"how would mankind handle the next nuclear plant catastrophy"_. I'd say: if it's really important data, redundancy will be even higher, and in the case of a "catastrophic failure", we'll probably just has to deal and live with it.

Comment: There are event notifications that you can subscribe to. For example, in sql server, you can have a deadlock graph emailed to you when a deadlock occurs. Also, you subscribe to replication fail events.

Comment: @dfri, Modern data-centers then just reduce the probabilities but cannot ensure that your data exists forever. With the 2-3 replicas, I wonder how less probable failures are.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan That was my point: we can't ensure that we'll not have another nuclear disaster, as little as we can ensure ourselves that some data will exist forever. You can only expect additional redundancy for very important data, as well as you ave redundancy *and* diversity in the cooling systems of a nuclear power plant. At the end of the day however, sooner or later we'll experience "disaster", and for data catastrophy: we'll most likely live through it (and prefer it to living next to the next nuclear plant that fails, contrary to what all safety statistics would say about that).

Comment: Subsequently, I recommend this question being migrated to philosophy.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NYC Tech Talk Series: How Google Backs Up the Internet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNliOm9NtCM&ab_channel=GoogleTechTalks) is a good explanation of how Google manages backing up and achieving reliability. A text-based explanation is [here](http://www.greendatacenternews.org/articles/share/695299/).

Most importantly the talk says the following:

- Redundancy is not a guarantee of integrity or recoverability.
- Tape is not obsolete.
- Isolation needs to be ensured in several different verticals: location, application layer problems, storage layer problems, media failure etc.
- Continuous backup and restoration, reading and writing from tapes even before there is a need for restoration.
- Automate steady-state operations as much as possible.
- Expect failures at a particular rate, investigate if the rate of failure changes.

Again, as the other answer says, it is only possible to cover all bases and ensure that the probability is so low and the window of data-loss (between one backup failing and being rebuilt from other backups) is extremely low.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume a given hard drive has a 50% chance of failing in a year (no that's not based on any real statistics, just an arbitrary overestimate).

That translates to a `.5 / (365 * 2) ~ 0.0057%` chance of failure in a given hour (assuming failure probabilities are evenly distributed over all the hours in a year).

A properly configured cluster should detect that a node has gone down fairly fast, and make additional copies of the data that node was responsible for.  I feel fairly safe in claiming that will happen in <1 hour (likely on the order of minutes at most).

So what we're really asking is - what's the chance that *all* nodes containing a single piece of data die so close in time that the data can't be re-replicated from an existing node.

For two copies of the data, this gives us `0.000057^2 ~ 3.25 * 10^-9 = 0.0000000325%`.

For three copies, `0.000057^3 ~ 1.86 * 10^-13 = 0.00000000000186%`.

And this doesn't account for additional offsite backups etc.  So while it's not impossible, I'd bet you're more likely to lose your data because a solar flare fries the entire data center than because of arbitrary hard drive failure.

Comment: So there are no additional measures being taken to ensure that data lives on, except for redundancy? The analysis makes sense. It is very very unlikely that someone loses data, much less likely than local storage, making it a good choice after all.

Comment: _"... you're more likely to lose your data because a solar flare fries the entire data center than because of arbitrary hard drive failure ..."_, or, to wrap up my comments from above, the neighbouring nuclear plant exploding and corrupting you data center with radioactive fallout ;) Again, I think this question belongs in philosophy.stackexchange (since question already states that data loss is _unlikely_, but _not impossible_); it doesn't really cover the scope of questions ment for SO.

Comment: @dfri, I was trying to understand if there are any measures other than replication were being used for a stronger guarantee. With this answer, I would argue that it belongs on SO.

Comment: disagree, this answer would belong on math.stackexchange if anywhere.  Remember, I'm _not_ giving a technical answer of other measures, just doing the math on how likely failure is

Comment: As Alec says, math.stackexchange / engineering.stackexchange or even philosophy.stackexchange, but not really stackoverflow, imho.